# Invisible multiplication in algeabric expressions

Tags: parsing, math

Parsing math expressions, would be better treat invisible multiplication (e.g. ab, meaning a times b, or (a-b)c, or (a-b)(c+d) ecc. ecc.) at level of the lexer or of the parser ?

Answer (score 4):

Implicit multiplication is a grammatical construct. Lexing is purely about recognizing the individual symbols. The fact that two adjacent expressions should be multiplied is not a lexical notion, as the lexer does not know about "expressions". The parser does.

If the lexer were responsible, you'd have to add lots of rules relating to adjacent tokens. For instance, insert a `×` token between two `IDENTIFIER`s, or an `IDENTIFIER` and a `NUMBER`, or a `NUMBER` and an `IDENTIFIER`, or between `)` and `IDENTIFIER`, or `IDENTIFIER` and `(`... except uh oh, `IDENTIFIER (` could be a function call, so maybe I need to look up `IDENTIFIER` in the symbol table to see if it's a function name...

What a mess!

The parser, on the other hand, can do this with a single grammar rule.

```
E → E '×' E
  | E E
```